# Dodge geom_points according to specific boxplot group/color

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

How can I dodge the `geom_points` into their specific boxplot group (provided by the aesthetic colour)? I have provided the following (simplified) example:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(diamonds, aes(x = cut, y = carat, color = color)) +
    geom_boxplot(outlier.shape = NA) +
    geom_point(aes(group = color))
```

Which provides the following plot:

[Boxplot with points not in corresponding boxplot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sWyjP.png)

I would like to have have the points aligned to the boxplot color (group) they belong to. How could I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To dodge your points and align them with the box plots use `position = position_dodge(width = .75)` where `.75` is the default width by which box plots get dodged:

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(diamonds, aes(x = cut, y = carat, color = color)) +
  geom_boxplot(outlier.shape = NA) +
  geom_point(aes(group = color), position = position_dodge(width = .75))
```

[image]